# Is there any way of creating a two-dimwnsional array with elements {'S2', 'R4'} in C?

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, types

Trying to find a way to create an array with a type that can store a string with numbers and leters in it. char doent work for that.

The array must be like the following. Array doesn't need to be modified.

If there is no way for that which data structure should be used?

Thanks for the answers.

```
`int main(void)
{
    char parsing_table[12][9] = {{'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1'},
    {'0','0','0','0','S6','0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','R3','0','0','0'},
    {'0','R3','0','0','0','0','accept','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','R1','0','4','0'}, 
    {'0','0','S11','0','0','0','0','0','5'},
    {'0','0','0','0','S8','0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','R5','0','0','0','0','0','1','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','2','0'},};

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            printf("%c ", parsing_table[i][j]);

        }
        puts("");
   }
}`
```

Comment: There are a lot of nuances to understand here. Will each element *always* be just 2 strings? Will it _point to_ 2 strings, or will it _store_ 2 strings? How long do the strings need to be? Is the 2D array expected to be mutable (changeable/editable) after initialization?

Comment: Update your question to show desired some usage of the 2D table, via desired functions, so we can know how you expect to _use_ it. Ex: `add_element(parsing_table, "S2", "R4")` might add element `{"S2", "R4"}` to the end of the 2D array. `write_element(row, col, "R4")` might write string `"R4"` to that row and column.

Comment: Start simple. Can you create a variable that has a *single* string with a number an a letter? Once successful, tweak to obtain an array.

Comment: If you're only using ASCII characters, you can encode your two-character string as a `word` or `int`. It's been a while since I used C, but I think something like `word foo = 'R3';` just might do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array of pointers to `char`:

```
char *arr[3][2] = 
{
    {"R2", "S3"},
    {"Z3", "D3"},
    {"Y4", "B3"},
};
```

Or array of strings

```
char arr1[3][2][3] = 
{
    {"R2", "S3"},
    {"Z3", "D3"},
    {"Y4", "B3"},
};
```

---

EDIT:

```
    for(size_t row = 0; row < 2; row++)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            printf("%s ", arr[row][col]);
            //or
            //printf("%s ", arr1[row][col])
        }
        puts("");
   }
```

Comment: how can I print these elements or reach them?

Comment: @Daghan see amended answer